# Numpy: rotate sub matrix m of M

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

If I knew the dimensions of each square submatrix m (2x2), and that the dimensionality of a large square matrix M was evenly divisible by the dimensionality m: M modulo m == 0.

Is there an efficient way to rotate submatrices within the following matrix M:

```
M = array([[ 1.,  2.,  1.,  2.],
           [ 3.,  4.,  3.,  4.],
           [ 1.,  2.,  1.,  2.],
           [ 3.,  4.,  3.,  4.]])
```

Such that the result is:

```
M* = array([[ 2.,  4.,  2.,  4.],
            [ 1.,  3.,  1.,  3.],
            [ 2.,  4.,  2.,  4.],
            [ 1.,  3.,  1.,  3.]])
```

In particular, it would be useful to force the use a function like numpy.rot90(), such that other rotations can be achieved e.g.

```
180: rot90(x, 2)
270: rot90(x, 3)
```

etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach using [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) and [`transpose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) -

```
m,n = M.shape
out = M.reshape(m//2,2,n//2,2)[...,::-1].transpose(0,3,2,1).reshape(m,n)
```

Sample run -

```
In [246]: M
Out[246]: 
array([[51, 70, 59, 38, 84, 18],
       [80, 25, 76, 43, 80, 48],
       [92, 98, 46, 14, 65, 47],
       [73, 31, 32, 79, 87, 70]])

In [247]: m,n = M.shape

In [248]: M.reshape(m//2,2,n//2,2)[...,::-1].transpose(0,3,2,1).reshape(m,n)
Out[248]: 
array([[70, 25, 38, 43, 18, 48],
       [51, 80, 59, 76, 84, 80],
       [98, 31, 14, 79, 47, 70],
       [92, 73, 46, 32, 65, 87]])
```

If you have to use [`np.rot90`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html), which works only on the first two axes, we need to use `transpose` twice, like so -

```
rot_arr = np.rot90(M.reshape(m//2,2,n//2,2).transpose(1,3,0,2),1)
out = rot_arr.transpose(2,0,3,1).reshape(m,n)
```

Comment: I'm finding it extremely difficult to apply this to other angles, such as 180, 270 etc.

Comment: @user1658296 Seems like there was a bug. Should be fixed in the edits just done.

Comment: Thanks, this is great, however, I am battling to see how this might generalize for m == 3x3 or 11x11, not just 2x2. Having to calculate the transpose axes here gets quite tricky.

Comment: @user1658296 I would think you just need to change all 2's in `reshape(m//2,2,n//2,2)` to those new numbers.